# How do I get a data variable from a Promise function using node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

This is my code:

```
const execBuffer = require('exec-buffer');
const gifsicle =  import('gifsicle');

execBuffer({
    input: encoder.out.getData(),
    bin: 'gifsicle',
    args: ['--output', execBuffer.output, '--lossy=100', '--optimize=03', execBuffer.input]
}).then(data => {
    console.log(data); // Works :-)
    let result = data; // Don't works :-(
});

return result;
```

How can I return the result variable from a promise in this case?